# Variadic Macro doesnt compile

Tags: c, macros, variadic

I am learning about macros from here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html#Variadic-Macros

All the examples have compiled so far, but this one doesnt:

```
#define eprintf(…) fprintf (stderr, __VA_ARGS__)
eprintf ("%s:%d: ", input_file, lineno)
```

This is the error:

```
error: "�" may not appear in macro parameter list
 #define eprintf(���) fprintf (stderr, __VA_ARGS__)

warning: __VA_ARGS__ can only appear in the expansion of a C99 variadic macro
 #define eprintf(…) fprintf (stderr, __VA_ARGS__)
```

This is how i generate the output file (i dont compile, i only want to see what the preprocessor does):

```
gcc -E macroTest.c -o macroTest
```

The file with the code inside is called macroTest.c

Answer (score 2):

Oh i found the mistake, … are not real dots, like those ...
if you copy and paste the code from the website it doesnt work, you have to replace the dots with ...